# How to check message status "message seen " in chat using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a chat app created using PHP, mySQL and jQuery. It's working fine for me. But now I want to add the "message seen" feature whenever the receiver sees the message. Or It can be a "tick" like feature as done in WhatsApp. The problem is that I don't know how to achieve this.

Here's the script which only works up to sending and receiving messages between users. What I have to do to implement this?

```js
$ = jQuery;
var currentID = null;
var chatTimer = null;
var oldhtml = "";

function fetch_data() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "select.php",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $('#live_data').html(data);
    }
  });
}

function fetch_chat() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "fetch_chat.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      id: currentID
    },
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#chatbox").show();
      $('#messages').html(data);
      $("div.area").show();
      if (oldhtml !== data) {
        $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight);
      }
      oldhtml = data;
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  fetch_data();

  setInterval(function() {
    fetch_chat();
  }, 500);

  $(document).on('click', '.first_name', function() {
    currentID = $(this).data("id1");
    fetch_chat();
  });

  $("#sub").click(function() {
    var text = $("#text").val();
    $.post('insert_chat.php', {
      id: currentID,
      msg: text
    }, function(data) {
      $("#messages").append(data);
      $("#text").val('');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the definition of "seen"  Have a look here for how to check something was visible in viewport https://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+is+visible+in+viewport

Comment: Seen Means That When The Receiver View The Received MessAge Then  The 'seen' Should Be Shown To The Sender

Comment: You need to elaborate on your data model... e.g. this question as it stands currently is too broad IMO

Comment: Just FYI you're using AJAX polling which is making a request to you server every 0.5s. This is *terrible* practice. A chat system should be built using WebSockets or Server Sent Events.

Comment: can u give me the concept

Comment: @mplungjan 
// in the name of the universe programmer //

thank you for  your answer 

i can solve my problem with your answer .

Answer (score -1):

you need a flag in your messages table,
when receiver fetches some messages, the status of these messages should be set to "seen", or if you want you can do this with ajax call after that the receiver opens the chat box or any event happened (like receiver clicks on chat box).
in chat boxes you must set id for every message, and every time you retrieve messages or check for new messages, you also must check "unseen" messages and send status of messages beside the message, and with your javascript,you must change class of these messages to "unseen" and other messages to "seen"

Answer (score -1):

I assume for a message to be "seen" it has to be visible from the chat html node($("#messages") in your case), meaning for some reason it can be hidden(e.g: another chat html node "active" in case there are several and only one can be active at a time, or maybe browser tab out of focus, or even the very message is out of the scroll view of the chat html node ...).

So, why not just add events listeners to it, listening whether its gets the "active" state or to the browser tab focus... When conditions met, just do an ajax query that will change the status(received, read(in this case) ...) of the message in the database by its id(assuming each message has a unique id set on it). Of course there should be a timer retreiving messages status, by then, in the sender side, you select read messages by their id and manage to get them "tick"ed as will, and even do something else.